# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am sorry I am posting this question again. I googled for it and found many posts and threads on stackoverflow and other ones, but none wokred for me.
I get this error message when I run my Windows Forms Application.
Here is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        Data Source=nhibernate.db;Version=3;New=True;
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
        NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
      </property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010, on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 Bit.
My project configuration is X86, and I tried the x86, x64 and ManagedOnly versions of the System.Data.SQLite.dll file, but none seemed to work.

Can anyone please help me with this?
P.S: I know there are similar threads to this one, but please don't close this thread because none of the solutions have worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Can you post the Exception and Stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the error:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly SQLite.NET could not be found. Ensure that the assembly SQLite.NET is located in the application directory or in the Global Assembly Cache. If the assembly is in the GAC, use <qualifyAssembly/> element in the application configuration file to specify the full name of the assembly.
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName)
   at NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Employee.App.SessionProvider.get_Session() in C:\Users\Ako\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Employee\Employee.App\SessionProvider.cs:line 28
   at Employee.App.EmployeeManager.get_Session() in C:\Users\Ako\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Employee\Employee.App\EmployeeManager.cs:line 14
   at Employee.App.EmployeeManager.Save(Employee employee) in C:\Users\Ako\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Employee\Employee.App\EmployeeManager.cs:line 56
   at Employee.App.frmMain.frmMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Ako\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Employee\Employee.App\frmMain.cs:line 23
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be with the driver creation, this suggests to me that the driver is not installed on your system correctly. I've just tested this and it works for me (ok I'm using monodevelop, not VS), I installed the Sqlite driver from here:

[ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/)

I then used this in my app.config file:

```
<session-factory>            
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=SimpleExample.sqlite;Version=3</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>         
        <mapping assembly="SimpleExample" />
    </session-factory>
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears that the SQLite assembly is not loaded hence the error:

Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly SQLite.NET could not be found. Ensure that the assembly SQLite.NET is located in the application directory or in the Global Assembly Cache. If the assembly is in the GAC, use  element in the application configuration file to specify the full name of the assembly.

you could preload the assembly using:

```
PreLoadAssembliesFromPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

private static void PreLoadAssembliesFromPath(string p)
{
    //S.O. NOTE: ELIDED - ALL EXCEPTION HANDLING FOR BREVITY

    //get all .dll files from the specified path and load the lot
    FileInfo[] files = null;
    //you might not want recursion - handy for localised assemblies 
    //though especially.
    files = new DirectoryInfo(p).GetFiles("*.dll",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    AssemblyName a = null;
    string s = null;
    foreach (var fi in files)
    {
        s = fi.FullName;
        //now get the name of the assembly you've found, without loading it
        //though (assuming .Net 2+ of course).
        a = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(s);
        //sanity check - make sure we don't already have an assembly loaded
        //that, if this assembly name was passed to the loaded, would actually
        //be resolved as that assembly.  Might be unnecessary - but makes me
        //happy :)
        if (!AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(assembly =>
          AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition(a, assembly.GetName())))
        {
            //crucial - USE THE ASSEMBLY NAME.
            //in a web app, this assembly will automatically be bound from the 
            //Asp.Net Temporary folder from where the site actually runs.
            Assembly.Load(a);
        }
    }
}
```